# composer.phar is not using the current directory's composer.json file

Tags: php, windows, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to update my dependencies and running `php [source_to_project]\composer.phar` update via Windows CMD, but the composer is reading the composer.json file from the php.exe folder. I don't have composer installed in my system, and I could only just run the `composer.phar` file. I checked also the location of my php.exe, and inside this directory, I can see the vendor/[package] that I'm trying to install from my project (which is from different directory, containing composer.phar)

Any idea why is this happening?

PS: I was able to install/update/require last week using the same process and now I cant.

Comment: _I don't have composer installed in my system_ Why not?

Comment: Because I'm not allowed to install composer. But we are allowed to use the composer.phar

Answer (score 0):

What is your COMPOSER env variable?

Maybe you can try this:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#environment-variables

> By setting the **COMPOSER** env variable it is possible to set the filename of composer.json to something else.
>
> For example:
>
> **COMPOSER=composer-other.json php composer.phar install**
>
> *The generated lock file will use the same name: composer-other.lock in this example.*

Answer (score 0):

Looking for like, a bunch of examples online, I figured out that I need to run the composer.phar while I'm on my project directory (ex.: `[PATH_TO_PROJECT_SOURCE] > [PATH_TO_PHP]php.exe composer.phar [COMPOSER_COMMAND]`), the problem was, I am running the composer command inside my php directory (since I am accessing the php executable to run the phar file, which should not be).